# Magento 2: Frontend workflow on windows too slow

Tags: magento2, development, windows, workflow

I am using **XAMPP** with **`php`** set up with **`memory_limit`** **2GB** and **`max_input_vars`** set to **10000.**

Is there anything else I can do to speed up performance of **Magento 2** on windows?

Comment: Try enabling cache if it's not already enabled.

Comment: The setup is for development purpose, I would rather not have to clear cache every time a change need to be reflected.

Comment: Yeah i also had same thought as I do same for Magento 1 but Magento 2 is dead slow in local machine. So instead waiting for page load, I felt its good to clear cache sometimes. Try once if helps else you can always disable cache :)

Comment: Try these works for me and better speed https://bitnami.com/stack/magento/installer

Comment: @AkhilGupta, but still for frontend having to deploy content for compiling less is a real pain.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/208432/magento-2-performance-issues/229939#229939 try these very useful steps

Comment: @RahulSingh these are useful for production environment, but thanks anyways.

Comment: try PHP7 under XAMPP

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report if available - 1 or more days uptime is helpful
F) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
G) SELECT name, count FROM information_schema.innodb_metrics ORDER BY name; 
for server tuning analysis and we will provide meaningful Global Variable suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be Xdebug in xampp\php\php.ini. Here're some solutions found around the web:

1. Run XAMPP as adminisrator and restart server.
2. In xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf, replace localhost with 127.0.0.1
   and restart server.
3. In Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts, add “127.0.0.1 127.0.0.1” &
   “127.0.0.1 localhost” and restart Window.
4. In Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts, un-comment “127.0.0.1
   localhost” and restart Window.
5. In php.ini, uncomment zend_extension =
   "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_eaccelerator_ts.dll" and restart server.
6. In php.ini, set xdebug.remote_enable=0.
7. In php.ini, set remote_host="localhost".
8. In php.ini, set xdebug.profiler_enable=0.
9. In php.ini, comment out all Xdebug statements.
10. If you using any antivirus on window pc, switch off the antivirus
     realtime scan (or add exclusion for XAMPP folders). Note: don't
     forget to restart the computer after the antivirus setting update
     (without that, the change couldn't take effect properly)
11. Try PHP7 under XAMPP

Answer (score 0):

In windows 10 you need to make real-time protection off under Windows Security, this will increase the performance in Windows